# Cannot find name 'Amplify' - project pipeline

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

This is a very noob question with an easy answer I'm sure.

I have an angular project which has a service spec test that makes use of Amplify, for example:

```
it(`should gracefully fail to log in`, fakeAsync(() => {
        spyOn(Amplify.Auth, 'signIn').and.returnValue(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject({message: 'simulated login error'});
        }));
```

This spec test belongs to a component I copied from another project and have not updated.

I have no issue with my local build, etc but when pushing to Kite, my pipeline fails with the following error:

```
src/app/services/login/login.service.spec.ts(648,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Amplify'.
```

I am unsure how to resolve this issue.

I have tried running an `npm install @aws-amplify/auth` command in the application folder and then pushed the package and package-lock but the pipeline still fails.

Is there something obvious I have missed?

Comment: Are you importing the Amplify module in your file? Did you save the package on your packages file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, a very simple solution (you can tell I'm new to front-end)

Required the following import:

`import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';`